# ZF2 translator is not working in controller?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to translate in the controller by `ServiceLocator`, but this is not translating and I have tried many sulotions in stackoverflow but with out success. My system uses multiple languages and my goal is to use transtor in view, controller, form and filter. Tranlator in my view is working. Any sugestion and help will be appreciated.

Not working in controller:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('my text',$myLocale);
```

My Application mudole.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
     'abstract_factories' => array(
         'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
         'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
     ),
     'factories' => array(
         'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
 'translator' => array(
     'locale' => 'en_US',// 'locale' => 'dk_DK',
     'translation_file_patterns' => array(
         array(

             'type'     => 'gettext',
             'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
             'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

I changed the local in mudole.config.php to another language but still not translating.

Comment: I don't post an answer as i think you get more value out of it when we may ask you why you need the translator in your controller in the first place? Translation should be handled in your view where the ``translator`` view helper is present and all build-in zf2 functions don't require the translator in the controller.

Comment: I agree and in my app almost all the translations are in the view, only in rare cases I have no choice but to tranlate in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the locale is sets not directly in the translating text, but by  `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->setLocale($locale)`, and now it is translating my text.

My Application mudole.config.php:

```
   'service_manager' => array(
         'factories' => array(
             'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
         ),
     ),
     'translator' => array(
         'locale' => 'en_US',
         'translation_file_patterns' => array(
             array(
                 'type'     => 'gettext',
                 'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                 'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
             ),
         ),
     ),
```

And in the controller:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->setLocale($locale);
echo $c=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('Book'); // Print(Danish): Bog
```

Answer (score 3):

**View Helper/Forms**

ZF2 ships with the view helper `Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate`; this is why you can already use the method `$this->translate($text)` in the view.

However *all* view helper classes that extend from [`Zend\I18n\View\Helper\AbstractTranslatorHelper`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-i18n/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AbstractTranslatorHelper.php#L49) (which includes all form view helpers) are also 'translation capable'.

You would need to pass in the translator using `$viewHelper->setTranslator($translator)` and enabling translation via `$viewHelper->setTranslatorEnabled(true)`.

**Controller Plugin**

Unfortunately there is no default plugin (that I could find) to handle translators in controllers; I guess you could argue that text content shouldn't be in the controller anyway.

You could easily create one such as the example below. The key is to pass your new `translator` service as a dependency via a factory.

```
namespace MyModule\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator as TranslatorService;

class Translator extends AbstractPlugin
{
    protected $translatorService;

    public function __construct(TranslatorService $translatorService)
    {
        $this->translatorService = $translatorService;
    }

    public function invoke($text = null, array $options = [])
    {
        if (null == $text) {
            return $this;
        }
        return $this->translate($text, $options);
    }

    public function translate($text, array $options = [])
    {
        return $this->translatorService->translate($text);
    }

}
```

And create the factory class.

```
namespace MyModule\Controller\Plugin;

use MyModule\Controller\Plugin\Translator;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class TranslatorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $controllerPluginManager)
    {
        $serviceManager = $controllerPluginManager->getServiceLocator();

        return new Translator($serviceManager->get('translator'));
    }
}
```

Register the service in `module.config.php`.

```
return [
    'controller_plugins' => [
         'factories' => [
             'translate' => 'MyModule\\Controller\\Plugin\\TranslateFactory',
         ]
    ],
];
```

Then you can just call it within a controller class.

```
// Directly
$this->translate($text, $options); 

// Or fetch the plugin first
$this->translate()->translate($text, $options);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but return empty text.?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [ZfTranslate](https://github.com/mikicaivosevic/zf2-translate-plugin) controller plugin.

#### installation

`composer require mikica/zf2-translate-plugin`

You need to register new module. Add in file config/application.config.php:

```
'modules' => array(
    '...',
    'ZfTranslate'
),
```

#### Usage in controller

```
<?php
$this->translate('translate word');
$this->translate('translate word', 'locale');
```

Comment: Can you,please, write the full address to your plugin?

Answer (score 0):

AlexP answer is the best way to do it.

**But remains a question, why your way doesn't work?**

It should work. But it doesn't because you are in different namespaces, so you are using distinct domains among the files. You doing something like that:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller;

class MyController {

   public function someAction() {
       $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('my text',__NAMESPACE__,$myLocale);
   }

}
```

While at your `module.config.php', you probably using this namespace:

```
namespace MyModule;

return array(
    //...
   'translator' => array(
       //...
    ),
);
```

**Note that in the example of the controller `__NAMESPACE__` is equals `MyModule\Controller`. While at the config file the `__NAMESPACE__` is equals `MyModule`. You need to fix it, passing the same value in both cases.**

**In other words, there are several approachs to solve this, like AlexP's, for instance. But, any one of them need to have the domain of translator (the value of the `'text_domain'` key) when you configure it equals the domain parameter (second paramater) of the `translate` method when you call it.**

The faster solution is changing the $domain parameter to string at the controller file:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('my text','MyModule',$myLocale);
```

Another solution should be creating a constant and using it at the files (controllers, views and config).

Comment: Yes I get the data from db and translating each one. With out namespace my view dosn't translate.

Comment: I can use now the transtor with out the text_domain, but still not translating.

Comment: The question remains the same: why my way doesn't work? As you mentioned :(

Comment: I answered it. I didn't said to you remove. I said to you change it to a value (_any string you want_) and used the same value when you calls the translate method.  Check the text above in bold. If it doesn't work yet, you may paste your code.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you put here how you are calling the translate method at the controller and how  you configured the translator at the module.config.php file with the changes I said?

Comment: Also, note that if you are creating the Translator without the text_domain it is set to 'default'. So you should call the translate method like this `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('my text','default',$myLocale);`.

Comment: Your answer below worked because in this case you are calling the text_domain 'default' in both places. Once the second parameter has as default a string 'default'. My comment above should work.